# Could not find kafka-clients-test.jar (org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.2-kafka-2.2.0)

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, apache-kafka, release

I am trying to make a release using gradlew.
I am getting below error.

is anyone familiar with this error?
I am able to build everything in local, issue is happening only when we do release.

```
17:11:15,004 ERROR - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
17:11:15,004 ERROR -
17:11:15,004 ERROR - * What went wrong:
17:11:15,004 ERROR - Could not resolve all files for configuration ':search-tools-service-application:compileClasspath'.
17:11:15,004 ERROR - > Could not find kafka-clients-test.jar (org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.2-kafka-2.2.0).
17:11:15,004 ERROR - Searched in the following locations:
17:11:15,004 ERROR - file:/local_repo/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/0.10.2-kafka-2.2.0/kafka-clients-0.10.2-kafka-2.2.0-test.jar
17:11:15,004 ERROR -
17:11:15,004 ERROR - * Try:
17:11:15,004 INFO  -
17:11:15,004 INFO  - Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
17:11:15,004 INFO  - Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
17:11:15,004 INFO  - See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
17:11:15,004 INFO  - 5 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 1 up-to-date
17:11:15,004 ERROR - Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
17:11:15,004 ERROR -
17:11:15,004 ERROR - * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
17:11:15,004 ERROR -
17:11:15,004 ERROR - BUILD FAILED in 13s
17:11:15,374 INFO  - Executing post-execute action...
17:11:15,375 ERROR - Step 'master>Publish Release - Git with Gradle>gradle publish using axion-release' is failed: Gradle build failed.
Errors occurred while build effective model from /local_repo/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.pom:
'build.plugins.plugin[io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin].dependencies.dependency.scope' for junit:junit:jar must be one of [compile, runtime, system] but is 'test'. in log4j:log4j:1.2.16

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':search-tools-service-application:compileClasspath'.

  > Could not find kafka-clients-test.jar (org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.2-kafka-2.2.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >   file:/local_repo/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/0.10.2-kafka-2.2.0/kafka-clients-0.10.2-kafka-2.2.0-test.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s

```
17:11:15,527 INFO  - Executing post-execute action...
17:11:15,527 ERROR - Step 'master>Publish Release - Git with Gradle' is failed: Composite step 'Publish Release - Git with Gradle' failed due to unsatisfied success condition.
17:11:15,644 INFO  - Executing post-execute action...
17:11:15,644 ERROR - Step 'master' is failed: Composite step 'master' failed due to unsatisfied success condition.
```

Comment: did you try going to local_repo/.m2/repository/ , and checking if the file exists?

Comment: some more information,this error is happening on quick build machine.in my local in dont have that jar file in maven but still build works fine, we are using gradle and in my gradle cache following jar is there /Users/gajjarj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/0.10.2-kafka-2.2.0/b185c7d7529f2cebffc831161f9457aff0f15779/kafka-clients-0.10.2-kafka-2.2.0-test.jar

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue, this is due to having `mavenLocal()` before `mavenCentral()` on the repositories section of your `build.gradle` file. Something else downloaded `kafka-clients-2.x.x.jar` into the local repository, and since gradle can find it there, it won't even look for the `kafka-clients-2.x.x-test.jar` in maven central anymore.

Try removing the original `org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients` dir under `~/.m2/repository` and try again. This solved the issue for me.

Comment: Just switching the order of `mavenLocal()` worked for me. thanks